# How to externalize strings to multiple files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, internationalization, externalizing

I have run Externalize Strings in Eclipse that generated a `messages.properties`.
That was translated to some other languages and the new files were created like `messages_de.properties` etc.

Now after adding some new strings how could I externalize them to all messages file?

If I simply run Externalize Strings again then it will update only `messages.properties` file
and therefore there will be inconsistency among the language files.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no, you cannot from the "Externalize Strings", translate a word into multiple locale.
The best way to mitigate that is to have some file diff tools ready to show you what new lines exist in `messages.properties` which do not exist in other `messages_xx.properties`.